# How can I use an CGAffineTransform scale and flip simultaneously

Tags: ios, cgaffinetransform, cgaffinetransformscale

I'm trying to convert an array of points using a `CGAffineTransform`. The scaling works perfectly, however the points are using the top left as (0,0) not the bottom left. like so...

[image: Upside down graph]

Normally I would simply use `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,-1);` but because I'm already performing a scale I can't add it to the existing transform.

Here's my current code

```
- (CGAffineTransform)transformFromValueToScreen
{
    CGRect fromRect = self.valueSpace;
    CGRect viewRect = self.screenSpace;

    CGSize scales = CGSizeMake(viewRect.size.width/fromRect.size.width,
                               viewRect.size.height/fromRect.size.height);

    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scales.width, 
                                                             scales.height);

    return transform;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming `fromRect.origin` is `CGPointZero`.

You need a compound transform that moves the origin to the lower left, flips the Y axis, and applies the scaling you want.

You can make a compound transform using the functions that modify a transform, like this:

```
- (CGAffineTransform)transformFromValueToScreen {
    CGRect fromRect = self.valueSpace;
    CGRect viewRect = self.screenSpace;

    CGSize scales = CGSizeMake(viewRect.size.width/fromRect.size.width,
                               viewRect.size.height/fromRect.size.height);

    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    // Move origin from upper left to lower left.
    transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, fromRect.size.height);

    // Flip the sign of the Y axis.
    transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1, -1);

    // Apply value-to-screen scaling.
    transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, scales.width, scales.height);

    return transform;
}
```

Comment: @soboxstudio If you think a change to the code would improve someone else's answer, please post a comment rather than suggesting an edit.

Comment: Thats perfect thanks, I'm still easily confused with the delicate ordering of transforms. Also can I suggest a slight change: `fromRect.bounds.height` should be `viewRect.size.heigh`

Comment: Yes both 'CGRects' have an origin of `CGPointZero`

Comment: @AdiInbar Can I amend the answer as I'm reluctant to accept an answer with a error in it (however small). Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be `fromRect.size.height`?  I think that should be correct.

Comment: @soboxstudio I understand, but I think it should be his call whether his answer should be changed.

Comment: @robmayoff I've tried both and `viewRect`look right. `fromRect` puts the whole transform to high. Cheers

Comment: Also for reference; it's for a graphing library I'm in the process of writing. https://github.com/BenjaminBriggs/BBGraphKit